# (not traditional) snake game in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, applet

I have to make a java applet looking like this [IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/15guqs4.png[/IMG]. The snake is made of 5 rect's, each one with 20px height and 20px width. With the use of a thread i have to make it move only at the edge's and clockwise (like in the picture). Here is my code, i know how to draw the snake, and i know how to make it move from left to right, i have trouble moving it top to bottom, right to left and bottom to top... any help would be appreciated :).

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JSlider;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Treta extends JApplet implements Runnable {

private int x = 0;
private int y = 0;
private int dx = 5;

public void init(){
    Thread t  = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    g.fillRect(x+20, y, 20, 20);
    g.fillRect(x+40, y, 20, 20);
    g.fillRect(x+60, y, 20, 20);
    g.fillRect(x+80, y, 20, 20);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    g.drawRect(x+20, y, 20, 20);
    g.drawRect(x+40, y, 20, 20);
    g.drawRect(x+60, y, 20, 20);
    g.drawRect(x+80, y, 20, 20);
}

public void run(){
    while(true){
        x += dx;
        repaint();
        if(x >= getWidth()-20){
            y += 5;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Try to get some understanding from this [Snake Game](https://github.com/AmanAgnihotri/SnakeGame)

Comment: Sorry that code didn't helped much, it would be great if someone could tell me what to add in my public void run() function, because i don't have any idea at the moment.

Comment: You have to add a game loop inside that run method that should be responsible for rendering and updating of objects in the game. Does it now make any clear? :P In the repository above, that game loop is already present. It isn't an applet though.